# How to Run a Specific delegate For iOS Version?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, ios11

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {

        let chatMessageStarModel = arrMentionChat[indexPath.row]
        if let key =  chatMessageStarModel.chatMessageMarkerID?.stringValue() {
        if let valueHeight = cellHeight[key] , valueHeight > 0.0{
               return valueHeight
           }
        }
        else {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
```

i want that function estimatedHeightForRowAt Only runs For Ios 11 or higher Not for Ios 10 or any other lower version . If i Use

```
 @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {

        let chatMessageStarModel = arrMentionChat[indexPath.row]
        if let key =  chatMessageStarModel.chatMessageMarkerID?.stringValue() {
        if let valueHeight = cellHeight[key] , valueHeight > 0.0{
               return valueHeight
           }
        }
        else {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
```

It Shows Error 
[image]

Another Approach i tried was :-

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
    if #available(iOS 11.0,*) {
        let chatMessageStarModel = arrMentionChat[indexPath.row]
        if let key =  chatMessageStarModel.chatMessageMarkerID?.stringValue() {
        if let valueHeight = cellHeight[key] , valueHeight > 0.0{
               return valueHeight
           }
        }
        else {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }

}
```

It Gives Error :- [image]

I Know I need to return something But if i return 0.0 or UITableViewAutomaticDimension than in Ios 10 this function will run and my case will get disturb .

**So how to run this function for only ios 11 and it does not run on ios 10 anyway to achieve this ?**

Comment: What iOS version is the target of your project?

Comment: ios 9  is the target

Comment: And.. are you defining the estimatedHeightForRowAt method directly on a UIViewController subclass or are you using a custom class conforming to UITableViewDelegate?

Comment: One final question: what do you mean with "in Ios 10 this function will run and my case will get disturb" -- does the table view display cell with wrong heights?

Comment: yes if this function run in Ios 10 my cell gets disturb

Comment: in ViewDIDLOAD I HAVE WRITTEN THIS   self.chatTable.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        self.chatTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to clearify your error message: in your first example you added `@available(iOS 11.0, *)` above the method; this does not mean *only use this method on iOS 11* but rather *this method is only available in iOS 11*. And apparently the compiler cannot cope with this ambiguity of both having and not having a protocol method conformance ("Schrödinger's Method", anyone?).

To work around this, you can create an iOS11-specific subclass of your delegate class and check the iOS version when setting it on the table view:

```
class Delegate: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate {
  // ... your version-independend delegate code goes here...
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
class IOS11Delegate: Delegate {
  // ... the iOS11-specific stuff goes here ...
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // ... your custom height estimation code goes here ...
  }
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
  private var delegate: Delegate?
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if #available(iOS 11.0,*) {
      delegate = IOS11Delegate()
    }
    else {
      delegate = Delegate()
    }
    tableView.delegate = delegate
  }
}
```

Not a very elegant solution, but it should work.